# Getting the set of all email addresses a gmail account has sent to or received from

Tags: api, gmail, google-api

The Google Contacts api seems to allow access only to a certain subset of all of the emails with which an account has communicated with.

Is there any efficient way to fetch such a list? (I.e. without actually accessing via POP/IMAP all of the email messages in the account...)

Comment: I suspect Google doesn't allow any access to this list through any of their API's. I don't know if this option is intentionally excluded or if it's simply oversight. You can see that someone was asking a similar question (with no response) on Google Groups back in '08 already: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/Google-Gadgets-API/BmVTi_gqDMk